# How to integrate Espressif Hal Module in Zephyr Build?

Tags: build, hal, esp-idf, zephyr-rtos, espressif-idf

As I am very new to Zephyr Build System as well as embedded programming, Someone might help me to know the exact steps need to taken care for integrating espressif hal modules in zephyr build system.

I have a main function where it calls esp_wifi.h for wifi API access, i can able to build and run the code from esp idf , same code i want to build using zephyr build system.

I included BOARD, ESPRESSIF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH, ZEPHYR_TOOLCHAIN_VARIANT as espressif and "hal espressif" modules as ZEPHYR_MODULES in CMakelist.

But still it is throwing errors like some espressif .h files not found and manually included all those files in Cmakelist. But now it throws error like Build system was not able to find the variables CONFIG_ESP32_WIFI_STATIC_RX_BUFFER_NUM, CONFIG_ESP32_WIFI_DYNAMIC_RX_BUFFER_NUM, CONFIG_FREERTOS_MAX_TASK_NAME_LEN but these varaiables got defined in sdkconfig.h

So I am not sure whether I am proceeding in correct direction or not.

Kindly share some links or steps to proceed for the integration of hal espressif modules in zephyr.